# Multiple variables in jQuery .click

Tags: jquery

I'm still new to jQuery and I ran into a small snag. How come the `.click` function won't work like this:

```
var $rowStartDate = $("span[id^=rowStartDate]");
var $rowEndDate = $("span[id^=rowEndDate]");

$($rowStartDate, $rowEndDate).click(function() { 
//Notice the variables in this selector
```

However, it works when I move the elements out of their variables:

```
$("span[id^=rowStartDate], span[id^=rowEndDate]").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second argument of [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is context. So you can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) instead:

```
$rowStartDate.add($rowEndDate).click(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

The two are very much different. You need to look at the definition of the [jQuery() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). When you say `$("span[id^=rowStartDate], span[id^=rowEndDate]").click(function() {` you are passing a string to the `jQuery()` function that then acts upon that string. When you say `$($rowStartDate, $rowEndDate).click(function() {` you are passing 2 parameters to the function which expects:

```
jQuery( selector [, context] )
jQuery( element )
jQuery( object )
jQuery( elementArray )
jQuery( jQuery object )
jQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use class for this.

Here is the Html

```
<span class='rowdate' id='rowStartDate'></span>
<span class='rowdate' id='rowEndDate'></span>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$('.rowdate').click(function(){
   //Maybe you want to know which span is clicked?
   if($(this).attr("id")=="rowStartDate"){
        //rowStartDate clicked function starts here
   }else{
        //rowEndDate clicked function starts here
   }
})
```